# Symfony file upload and UploadedFile::getClientSize()

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload

I'm building file upload **without** `Doctrine` and such no validation via annotations or YAML available to me. Symfony presents uploaded file as `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile` object, which has `getClientSize()` method, description:

> Returns the file size.
>
> It is extracted from the request from which the file has been
>   uploaded. Then is should not be considered as a safe value.

Then what should be considered safe? What then Symfony uses to validate `Doctrine` document entity via annotations or YAML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$file->getSize()`. Symfony [`UploadedFile`](http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html) extends [`File`](http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.html) which in turn extends [SplFileInfo](http://php.net/SplFileInfo), which itself has `::getSize` method.

As for Symfony Validation component, it uses PHP `filesize` function directly: [FileValidator line 142](https://github.com/symfony/Validator/blob/master/Constraints/FileValidator.php#L142)

Comment: Sweet! Apparently, I didn't dig deep enough. Thank you!